# Background code no longer executes in Android 10

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-service

We have developed an application which will help us track a BLE device and trigger alarm when the BLE device gets disconnected from the application. When it disconnects the application is programmed to trigger calls and messages to three defined mobile numbers which it seems to do when the application is installed in devices which have Android version until 9( included android 7,8,9). The issue arises when we install the application in the Android 10 the the calling and messaging action is not happening when the application is running in the background. Then in Android 11 even the application is running the call and messages are not going to the configured mobile devices.

We have checked the code execution part and the calling function, messaging function is triggered when the device is disconnected but in Android 9 the calling and messaging are happening as expected but in Android 10 & 11 it is not working.

So please help us sort this issue as we are nearing the deployment timeline for the project. Any help would really be appreciated.

**Permissions added in Manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

**SMS Function**

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
for (int i = 0; i < contactJsonArray.length(); i++) {
try {
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(contactJsonArray.get(i)), null, text, null, null);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

**CALL Function**

```
  int con_length = contactJsonArray.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < con_length; i++) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
      try {
           intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactJsonArray.get(i)));
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
           if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
            }
            startActivity(intent);
                //Log.e("call123",String.valueOf(contactJsonArray.get(i)));

         } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
         try {
              sleep(60000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }
```

Comment: Have you read about the [background restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) introduced in Android 10? I am not sure they apply to your app. But, unfortunately, they are pretty severe restrictions compared to Android 9. Many affected developers found they had to make relatively radical changes, and a few just couldn't adapt.

Comment: You must request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION. I have written a library help doing just that. Please have a look https://github.com/warting/permissions-ui